# Can I deal combat damage with a 1/1 Walking Ballista and deal damage with its ability?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Rules Question:

1. Player A attack with 1/2 creature
2. Player B block with [Walking Ballista](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWalking%20Ballista%5d) with 1 +1/+1 counter
   And now can player B use Walking Ballista activation ability, after combat damage but before it go to graveyard, to kill 1/2 creature?

Comment: You could have done this prior to 2010 when they change the rules: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3265/can-someone-explain-the-damage-on-the-stack-rule-change

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot.  Going to the graveyard (due to damage) is a State-Based action that happens before either player gets priority.  Without priority, you can't activate Ballista's ability.

> 704.3. Whenever a player would get priority (see rule 116, “Timing and Priority”), the game checks for any of the listed conditions for state-based actions, then performs all applicable state-based actions simultaneously as a single event. If any state-based actions are performed as a result of a check, the check is repeated; otherwise all triggered abilities that are waiting to be put on the stack are put on the stack, then the check is repeated. Once no more state-based actions have been performed as the result of a check and no triggered abilities are waiting to be put on the stack, the appropriate player gets priority.